# KOMA script: how to create an empty page after each chapter heading?

Tags: koma-script, titlesec

I'm using KOMA script's `scrbook`, and would like to have each chapter title to be in its own page, followed by an empty page.

Currently it's acheived with `titlesec`, by the following code (using XeLaTeX):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{mwe}

%%%%%%%%%%%    EMPTY CHAPTER PAGE %%%%%%%%%%%
% from http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-reallyblank.html
\let\origdoublepage\cleardoublepage
\newcommand{\clearemptydoublepage}{%
\clearpage
{\pagestyle{empty}\origdoublepage}%
}
\let\cleardoublepage\clearemptydoublepage

%%%%%%%%%%%    CHAPTERS   %%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[center]{titlesec}
\titleformat
    {\chapter} % command
    [block] % shape
    {\huge} % format
    {} % label
    {0.5ex} % sep
    {
    % add code to start on even pages
        \centering
    } % before-code
    [
    \cleardoublepage
    ] % after-code
\assignpagestyle{\chapter}{empty}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Manta Ray}
    \blindtext
    \section{Taxonomy}
    \blindtext[10]
    \chapter{Mobula}
    \blindtext
    \section{Life style}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

Since `titlesec` and KOMA aren't good friends, I would like to "translate" `titlesec` code to `scrlayer-scrpage`.

However, the documentation is very confusing, and I couldn't find relevant examples on the Internet as well.

In the [documentation](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), page 83, I found this:

> ```
> Suppose you have defined your own page style for initial chapter pages with
> the scrlayer-scrpage package (see chapter 5). You have given this page style
> the fitting name of chapter. To actually use this style, you must redefine
> \chapterpagestyle in this way:
> \renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{chapter}
> ```

Sound promising...
But I couldn't find in chapter 5 how to create my own page style.

Comment: `scrlayer-scrpage` is a page style package not a chapter style package. So it is not an alternative to `titlesec`. But KOMA-Script classes have build in features for chapter heading configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A heading page on its own with a centered heading and a following empty page after the heading is typically for parts. Therefore one possibility would be to change the heading style from `chapter` to `part`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=part]{chapter}

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Manta Ray}
    \blindtext
    \section{Taxonomy}
    \blindtext[10]
    \chapter{Mobula}
    \blindtext
    \section{Life style}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

If you don't want to show the chapter number in the heading, but still give the heading a logical number, you can also change `\chapterformat`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[style=part]{chapter}
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}% remove chapter number
% \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% also for the page header
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Manta Ray}
    \blindtext
    \section{Taxonomy}
    \blindtext[10]
    \chapter{Mobula}
    \blindtext
    \section{Life style}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

To change the font you can use either `\setkomafont{chapter}{…}` or the `font` option of `\RedeclareSectionCommand`. Please see the manual for other options of the command, e.g., to change the skips before or after the heading.

Another solution could be to redefine `\chapterheadendvskip`. In this case, you also need to change `\raggedchapter` to center the heading:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{mwe}
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadendvskip}{\cleardoubleemptypage}
\let\raggedchapter\centering
\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{}
\begin{document}
    \chapter{Manta Ray}
    \blindtext
    \section{Taxonomy}
    \blindtext[10]
    \chapter{Mobula}
    \blindtext
    \section{Life style}
    \blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

BTW:

- KOMA-Script already has `\cleardoubleemptypage` and by default empty pages already have page style `empty`.
- And KOMA-Script already has an empty page style. So if you want to use page style empty for the chapter page in the second example, you can simply use `\renewcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{empty}`. However, if you want to define your own page style see chapter 17 and 18 in the manual.

Comment: 1. In the second suggestion, I don't see the difference between enabling and disabling `% \renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}% also for the page header`.
2. What are the pros and cons of the second suggestion vs. the third suggestion?

Comment: @Zvika 1. Have a look at the page header of, e.g. page 4. 2. There are only two suggestions so I do not understand what you mean with "third suggestion"?

Comment: By `suggestion` I meant `code snippet`. You wrote 3 code snippets. My second question was what are the considerations to prefer the second code snippet over the third one, and vice-verse (beside that one is using `chapterheadendvskip` and one is not...)

Comment: @Zvika Again: For the first question see any left page of a chapter (but the empty left page after the chapter page). And for the second question: Changing `\chapterheadendvskip` may conflict with other changes of `\chapterheadendvskip`. Changing of the heading style may conflict with other configurations of the chapter heading. See the manual for the differences of heading style `chapter` and heading style `part`. What is the better suggestion? Don't known. It depends on what else you are doing. BTW: A third suggestion could be to use `\part`/`\addpart` instead of `\chapter`.

Answer (score 0):

To get a pagebreak after the chapter title, just add one command, see this MWE:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\newpage}

\begin{document}


\blinddocument{}


\end{document}
```

I did not test for side effects, though.

The second part of your question isn't clear to me: Would you like to have a completly empty page after the page of each chapter title, or a page with headings and a page number?

If the page has to be empty: `\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\cleardoubleemptypage}`, like suggested in the other answer.

If you'd like to have a page with headings: `\renewcommand{\chapterheadendvskip}{\newpage\mbox{}\newpage}`.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Yes, you are right, thank you, I didn't get the second part of the question. I edited my answer.

Comment: There is also a `\cleardoublestandardpage`, that could be used to have an empty page with page head and foot (or `\cleardoubleplainpage`) for empty page with page number only and even `\cleardoublepageusingpagestyle` do use any other page style.